# how to get event of on completion of youtube video in android webview

Tags: android, webview, youtube

I was able to play youtube video on `WebView`. I want to finish/close/destroy the `WebView` automatically when youtube video is completed.

here is my code:

```
  WebView engine = new WebView(this);
  engine.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  engine.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
  engine.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/embed/bIPcobKMB94?autoplay=1&rel=0&loop=0");//&enablejsapi=1");
  setContentView(engine);
```

Actually I was trying to play songs (audio/video) from the playlist when audio is there in playlist it played in my custom player and when youtube video is there is played in `WebView` and songs are playing one after another automatically onCompletion. Youtube video played in `WebView` but after the completion of video, webview still open (not going to be destroy/finish). How could I finish `WebView` and get back to previous activity?

Comment: have you figured out with the solution

Answer (score 1):

Android's webview implementation hides the underlying MediaPlayer related APIs and callbacks. The only situation when the application comes into picture is when a user tries to go full screen (clicking on full screen icon in video embedded in WebView). In this case, onShowCustomView() is called back provided the application has implemented and registered a WebChromeClient callback. There is no way for you to know when a video has finished playing inside a webview.

I know this isn't what you asked: but why not use the youtube app by dispatching an intent to play the url? You can use the startActivityForResult() method which will call back your onActivityFinished() API (you have to implement this callback) with a result code. Will this not work for you?

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i don't want that user go outside my app. Otherwise using startActivityForResult it is possible